# How to create a symbolic link to a BusyBox binary?

Tags: relative-path, symlink, busybox

So currently I have Busybox installed on an embedded kernel in its /system/bin/ folder and can call manually to the VI editor by typing `busybox vi` and vi will be executed. **HOWEVER**, I want to create a symbolic link to `busybox vi` by just typing `vi file.txt` instead of `busybox vi file.txt` so I won't have to type busybox every time. How to do this? I already tried this:

**Installing Busybox**

If the Busybox executable is renamed to one of the commands it supports, it will act as that command automatically:

```
 ln -s busybox pwd
 ./pwdfrom
```

...from Busybox's website but still doesn't work, all it says is on my terminal for `which` command is:

```
127|root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # ln -s busbox which
root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # which ls
/system/bin/sh: which: not found
127|root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # ls -la which lrwxrwxrwx root root 1970-01-03 18:15 which -> busbox
```

any ideas what I'm doing wrong? My $PATH is: `/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin`

Comment: *"I already tried this..."* -- Where's the explanation of what you did?  Show the results, i.e. do a **ls**`of the link that you created.

Comment: `127|root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # ln -s busbox which
root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # which ls
/system/bin/sh: which: not found
127|root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # ls -la which
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-01-03 18:15 which -> busbox
root@nitrogen6x:/system/bin # which
/system/bin/sh: which: not found` And thanks for the -1.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to get this to work

**HERE'S HOW:**

1. So I went to root directory:

   `cd /`
2. Then I remounted the /system/ directory:

   `mount -o rw,remount /system`
3. Then I went into the binary folder where busybox was located:

   `cd /system/bin/`
4. Then I used the link command for the busybox binary I wanted:

   `ln -s busybox lsusb` (remember you must be in `/system/bin` directory already)

## For Already Linked Files:

5. For already linked files like `ls`, remove the linked file and replace with Busybox binary instead (I know it sounds crazy but you can always go back to system's binary utilities):

   `sudo rm /system/bin/ls 
    ln -s busybox ls` (remember you must be in `/system/bin` directory already)
6. You should get something like this when you do `ls -l ls`:

   `lrwxrwxrwx    1 0        0                7 Jan  4 21:53 ls -> busybox`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you want is `busybox --install`? It creates symbolic links for you. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679585.

Answer (score 0):

One point to consider is that you have to be on the same file system.
For example if you are trying to create a symbolic link from one mounted file system to a file on another file system then that's an issue.
If your / and /usr are not on the same mounted file system as there might be the case for embedded systems, then you cannot create a symbolic link /usr/bin/which to point to /bin/busybox.
One possible solution is to put a copy of busybox binary in /urs/bin and create link to that.

Comment: I don't think this answer/comment is correct. Symlinks (via "ln -s") work just fine across filesystems. It is HARD links (via "ln" alone) that cannot.